# How to change the button name after click on it using ajax

Tags: forms, ajax

I am a newbie in drupal. I created a form that perform ajax action. How can I change the button name after click by using ajax.

```
function auktion_fav_form($form, &$form_state, $auktion_id) { 
  form['add_to_fav'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#id' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t($value),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'auktion_fav_submit',
      'wrapper' => 'submit',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    )
  );
  return $form;
}
function auktion_fav_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['add_to_fav']['#value'] = "remove from favourite;
  return $form['add_to_fav'];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hook form alter define your submit value . Below is small piece of code .

```
   $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Calculate'),
     '#prefix' => '<div id="div-example">',
     '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'example_ajax_form_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'div-example',
         'method' => 'replace',
      ),
     );

function example_ajax_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submit']['#value'] = 'New value';
    return $form['submit']; 
  }
```

Comment: Form button does not change to new Value. But the response contain new value

Comment: i tried the whole code as it is and posted it .. I wander y it not changing..are you doing something in form alter or is it a new form

Comment: its a new form.. and I got the  new content as #value, but not changed the value of the button dynamically. If I refresh the page it will show the changes..

Comment: are you doing this    '#value' => t($value), if yes where is $value defined in your form ??

Comment: yes..$value is conditionally filled value.. if in value in my database then `$value = "Remove from favourite"` else `$value = "Add to favourite"`

Comment: can you once try the code that i posted and tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39387/discussion-between-shreya-shetty-and-vishnu-jayan).

Answer (score 1):

you can use hook_form_alter

```
 yourmodule_form_alter{

   $form_state['values']['add_to_fav'] = "remove from favourite";        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by changing your code to

```
function auktion_fav_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['add_to_fav']['#value'] = "remove from favourite";
  return $form['add_to_fav'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code in your themes js file:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#submit").click(function(){ 
    switch (jQuery(this).val()) {
      case 'Your-button-text-here':       **//this is the text of the button which you want to change now change it with your button name**

        jQuery('#submit').val('remove from favourite');
        break;
    };
  });
});
```